# General rescue throughout controller when id not found - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord, rescue

I have stumbled upon a situation where my application looks for an id that does not exist in the database. An exception is thrown. Of course, this is a pretty standard situation for any web developer.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336593/rescue-from-activerecordrecordnotfound-in-rails/2337906#2337906) I know that using rescue deals with the situation pretty neatly, like so:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound #customer with that id cannot be found
    redirect_to action: :index        #redirect to index page takes place instead of crashing
end
```

In case the customer cannot be found, the user gets redirected to the index page. This works absolutely fine.

Now, this is all nice, but I need to do the same rescue attempts in actions like show, edit, destroy, etc, i.e. *every* controller method that needs a specific id.

Having said that, **here's my question:**
Isn't there any way to generally tell my controller that if it can't find the id in any of its methods, it shall redirect to the index page (or, generally, perform a specific task)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You must use `rescue_from` for this task. See example in the [Action Controller Overview Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue_from)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

  private

  def record_not_found
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that does the trick, thank you! Out of curiosity: why should that method be private?

Comment: Just for cleanliness: the method does not need to be visible to other controllers, that's why it is declared private. It would work equally if the method is not declared private.

Comment: You could also add a flash message 
    flash[:notice] = "No record found"

Comment: It is very nice and really help me

Answer (score 8):

Rails has a built-in [`rescue_from`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) class method:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :index
  ...
end
```

Comment: This looks very elegant. I tried it, but it leaves me with an empty page in the browser, and in the url it still says `customers/:id`. Am I missing something? It appears to me it tries to render index instead of redirecting to it.

Comment: You're right.. try something like what Baldrick suggests below (i.e, an intermediate method with a redirect).

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about doing this within a single controller (as opposed to doing this globally in every controller) then here are a couple options:

You can use a before_filter to setup your resource:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_customer, :only => [ :show, :update, :delete ]

  def show
  end

  private

  def get_customer
    @customer = ActiveRecord.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to :action => :index
  end
end
```

Or you might use a method instead. I've been moving in this direction rather than using instance variables inside views, and it would also help you solve your problem:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # Uses customer instead of @customer
  end

  private

  def customer
    @customer ||= Customer.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to :action => :index
  end
  helper_method :customer
end
```

Comment: The word "globally" caught my attention. Is there a way to do this throughout all controllers? That would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I think to do what I described in a global way might require a little metaprogramming. But to simply rescue the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound globally you could use rescue_from in your ApplicationController.

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, I would recommend that you use `Model.find_by_id(id)` as opposed to `Model.find(id)`. Instead of throwing an exception, `.find_by_id` returns `nil`. if the record could not be found.

Just make sure to check for nils to avoid `NoMethodError`!

P.S. For what it's worth, `Model.find_by_id(id)` is functionally equivalent to `Model.where(id: id)`, which would allow you to build out some additional relations if you want.

Comment: I know that you mean that `where` and `find_by` are similar in that neither throws an exception if the record can't be found, but it's worth noting that `where` returns an active-record relation whereas `find_by` returns a single record (if not `nil`). Also, I think I'd rather throw an exception than catch it and prevent null-pointer exceptions everywhere. Not sure what the value in that is.