# Rails URL Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Article` and `Comment`.

An `Article` `has_many` `Comments`.

When I visit `comments#show`, `articles/1/comments/2`, I am able to access comments that do not belong to the article.

For example, in this case, `comment` with id 2 does not belong to `article` with id 1, yet I am still able to access this URL.

Any idea why?

Comment: Your controller needs to enforce this

Comment: By adding this to the query that loads the comment - there's no magic going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you nest URLs, you are making an inference that the child resource belongs to the parent resource, and should be scoped to it.

Unless you enforce this scoping, you might as well not use nested URLs. Nesting the URL makes the `article_id` available in the params of the comments controller.

Say you wanted to show a single comment.

```
def CommentsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In response to your comment below, you generally want this to fail. In production, a missing resource responds with a 404 response code (page not found).

If you do want manual error handling, you can do something like this:

```
def CommentsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_article_or_redirect_to_root

  def show
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

private

  def set_article_or_redirect_to_root
    @article = Article.find_by(params[:article_id])
    redirect_to root_path unless @article
  end
end
```

Notice I am using [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by), which does not raise an error if the article resource isn't found (as opposed to [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)).

Otherwise, if you want to use [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), you need to rescue the resulting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error (for example, maybe you want to record the error in the logs).

```
  def set_article_or_redirect_to_root
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! how would you write something like that in case of an error? `unless @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to root_path
  end`

Comment: to rescue from the not found, you rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336593/rescue-from-activerecordrecordnotfound-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce this in your controller with something like this:

```
@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
```